# Why does my camera when moving up or down (camera has a top view) move to the y coordinate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why does my camera when moving up or down (camera has a top view) move to the y coordinate?
**Here is the code:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ScrollWheelMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool DragMoveActive;
    private Vector2 LastMousePos;

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 inputDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        float DragPanSpeed = 3f;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
            DragMoveActive = true;
            LastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(2))
        {
            DragMoveActive = false;
        }

        if (DragMoveActive)
        {
            Vector2 mouseMovementDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - LastMousePos;

            inputDir.x = mouseMovementDelta.x * DragPanSpeed;
            inputDir.z = mouseMovementDelta.y * 6f;

            LastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        float moveSpeed = 3f;
        Vector3 moveDir = -transform.right * inputDir.x + -transform.forward * inputDir.z;
        transform.position += moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
    }
}
```

I want my camera to move only along the coordinates x and z.

I tried to change the code with coordinates, speed. I also tried to constantly set the coordinates y = 40

Comment: you can assign `moveDir.y = 0` if you want, before doing `transform.position += `.  Is that the effect you're going for?

Comment: I think, the problem was because you use **transform.right** and **transform.forward**, which can return vectors with y != 0 (due to the rotation of the object the script attached to). Maybe it would be better to replace it with **Vector3.right** and **Vector3.forward**?